# Upload de múltiplos arquivos em PHP

Tags: php, xml, upload

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em **PHP** onde será feito importação de NF-e no formato **XML**. O problema é que o cliente irá fazer essa importação de múltiplos arquivos ao mesmo tempo, e terei que pegar os dados de cada arquivo e ir inserindo algumas informações na base de dados. Neste caso, avaliei o *uploadify* que por sua vez, existe uma versão em HTML5 que é pago, e outra versão free que renderiza na página em forma de swf.

Existe alguma outra biblioteca de upload de múltiplos arquivos em PHP que poderia resolver esse tipo de problema?

Comment: Fora o uploadify vc tentou algum outro plugin? tem o [jquery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o plugin [jQuery Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). Nos arquivos do plugin existe um exemplo de classe para upload de imagem. Porem é bem complexa.

Para obter os dados que este plugin enviar, você pode utilizar igual está [especificado no manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php).

Quando um formulário é enviado, os arrays `$_FILES['userfile']`, `$_FILES['userfile']['name']`, e `$_FILES['userfile']['size']` são inicializados.

Vamos supor que você faça o upload dos arquivos `review.html` e `xwp.out` utilizando o formulário a seguir

```
<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Neste caso em `$_FILES['userfile']['name'][0]` irá ter o valor `review.html` e `$_FILES['userfile']['name'][1]` irá ter `xwp.out`.

As outras variáveis de arquivo tambem possuem o mesmo comportamento

```
$_FILES['userfile']['size'][0]
$_FILES['userfile']['name'][0]
$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][0]
$_FILES['userfile']['size'][0]
$_FILES['userfile']['type'][0]
```

Utilizando isto você pode implementar uma classe de upload que te atenda, e poderá utilizar o plugin que citei.

Uma outra maneira que creio ser mais viável para você, é mandar o arquivo zipado.

Você pode fazer a leitura dos arquivos compactados usando o `ZipArchive`

```
// Criando o objeto
$z = new ZipArchive();

// Abrindo o arquivo para leitura/escrita
$open = $z->open('teste.zip');
if ($open === true) {
    // Listando os nomes dos elementos
    for ($i = 0; $i < $z->numFiles; $i++) {
        // Obtendo o conteúdo pelo indice do arquivo $i
        $fileContent = $z->getFromIndex($i);
        // Aqui você faz o parser do XML e realiza sua manipulação
    }
    // Fechando o arquivo
    $z->close();
} else {
    echo 'Erro: '.$open;
}
```

[Aprenda mais sobre o ZipArchive](http://rubsphp.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/manipulando-arquivos-zip-pelo-php.html)